# What's the phrase for being punished because of someone else's folly, guilt or mistake?

Tags: phrases, expressions

What's the phrase for being punished because of someone else's folly, guilt or mistake?

For example, a school bully frightens his classmate into helping him cheat in the exam. The teacher notices and rips up both students' exam papers. Here, the bully's classmate is punished too, but actually he's not as guilty as the bully.

Comment: I'd say he is as guilty. You have to confront fear and stand up to bullies, not just cooperate with them.

Comment: Roughly, that's a scapegoat or a whipping boy